# SSRS White space issue

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 scenarios 

Scenario 1:

abc Ins Services,

             

123 Pine St Fl 23

San Francisco, CA, USA

SCENARIO 2:

abc Ins Services,

#4567

123 Pine St Fl 23

San Francisco, CA, USA
All fields are dynamic and I used trim in every expression but white space still comes as shown in scenario 1 ,I dont want this white space.

Answer (score 0):

The space that you're seeing there isn't just a `space` character, it's a line return. These can be stored in the strings in your database as part of the address. They are hard to see when you preview results in a program like SSMS. The `Trim` function only removes spaces. Line returns are usually made up of ASCII characters 10 and 13. In order to remove line returns you can use the `Replace` function like so:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(<string to search in>, CHR(13), ""), CHR(10), "")
```

This allows you to add your own line returns where you actually want them.

Comment: Thanks Steven!! I'll get back to you in case if it doesn't solve my concern.